# Latex-Suite Mapping Using Fullwidth Characters

Tags: cjk, vim, vim-latex

Currently I am using Latex-Suite to edit an document that contains CJK characters for more than 90%, and therefore mainly using an input method that outputs [fullwidth characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms). I tried to define some mappings that use fullwidth characters but in vain; for example,

```
call IMAP('￥ｅｔ', '\Expectation <++>', 'tex')
```

So is it possible to define mappings with fullwidth characters?
Or I always have to change to a English input method for typing commands and then change back(that would keep using `ctrl+space`.......)?

Comment: Well, `IMAP` function does not work for Unicode characters. It seems that you should use a better input method so that you can use one key, e.g. a shift key, to change the mode. Usually you always have to change the mode some way to input CJK characters and Latin characters.

Comment: Thank you for advice! I have tried to customize the input method so that life becomes easier...